# XML file that starts with a # (hash)

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to load XML files with `XDocument.Load(stream)`, but some files are declared as

```
#<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root>
</root>
```

Because of the starting `#` I am getting an `XmLException` with the message

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

To handle this anomaly, I have this fall back idea:

```
XDocument? xDoc = null;
var fileName = "C:\dummy.xml";

try
{
    await using var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    xDoc = await XDocument.LoadAsync(fileStream, LoadOptions.None, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //my idea would be, if an exception occured
    //- read the file into memory 
    //- verify if it starts with '#'
    //- drop the '#'
}
```

Is there a better way to handle files with the `#`?

Is the `#` some XML specification I am unaware of?

Comment: You say you're loading "XML files" - but those files *aren't* valid XML files. I would personally handle it somewhat differently (unconditionally loading into memory, potentially skipping the "#" and *then* parsing, so you don't need any try/catch - but fundamentally, it's *not an XML file* if it starts with "#". I would at least *try* to fix the problem further upstream, with whatever is creating the file. (If it's making this error, there may be other problems as well that you just haven't seen yet.)

Comment: @JonSkeet - sadly, I can't fix the root problem - the files are outputed by an SAP system, and I am forced to deal with them as they are, nothing I could change about that, not really in the position to tell SAP to change their output - the idea of dropping the `#` as a fallback is because every non-SAP system (~10 different systems) all have xml files without the `#` and I wouldn't know prior to reading the xml file if it is SAP or a different system

Comment: You might want to consider having a separate "fix the problem" phase, which *just* checks whether the first character is '#', and copies to a new file without the '#' if so. Just an option to consider - without knowing more context, it's hard to say. But I *tend* to prefer to work around any kinks in one phase of a pipeline, then work on the basis of "everything should be fine, and if it isn't, that's a serious problem rather than something to workaround".

Comment: @JonSkeet -  seems to be a valid option, if you have time do you mind wrting an answer how you would do it? can I use streams `Peek` to more effiently read the first character?

Comment: If the files are always UTF-8, I'd open the file with `File.OpenRead`, read the first byte with `Stream.Read`, and detect if it's `#`. If it is, use `File.Create` to create a new file stream, then `Stream.CopyTo` to copy the *rest* of the original file to the new file.

Comment: I wouldn't write that as an answer, as it's not really an answer to the question you've asked. You could modify the question to "how would I fix this situation" without reference to the XML parsing part.

Comment: Whenever you get bad XML (files that should be XML but aren't) your first choice should be to find out where they got corrupted and fix the problem so it doesn't happen again. If you can't do that, then repairing the files to make them well-formed XML is a last resort. Fortunately in this case the corruption is fairly simple and easily fixed by preprocessing the file before you pass it to the parser.

Comment: By the way, the "#" character is often called "hash" (though it has a variety of other names as well), but it's not a "hashtag". A hashtag is a keyword marked out by means of an initial hash character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably go through a separate phase beforehand, copying files without their first byte, where appropriate. For example:

```cs
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles("*.xml"))
{
    // Note: this assumes all XML files are UTF-8.
    using (var input = File.OpenRead(file))
    {
        int firstByte = input.ReadByte();
        if (firstByte != '#')
        {
            continue;
        }
        string tmp = file + "-tmp";
        using (var copy = File.Create(tmp))
        {
            input.CopyTo(copy);
        }
        // Close the stream so we can rename.
        input.Close();
        // Move the original file to a backup, and the temporary to the original name
        File.Move(file, Path.ChangeExtension(file, ".bak"));
        File.Move(tmp, file);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Or in XPath, `unparsed-text($uri) => substring(2) => parse-xml()`.